# Does Android allow revoking permissions?

Tags: android, permissions

I saw applications for rooted devices allowing to revoke specific permissions given to app. Does non-root Android device allow this with some code?

UPDATE:
Having keyboard app with permissions FINE LOCATION and internet - it is weird to allow such permissions. They are not necessary to allow me to type.
I can imagine only one reason - to collect my login info.

Comment: @DerGolem : can you elaborate? I fail to see how revoking a right hurts security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not presently possible by any supported means. Android presently does not allow the *user* to revoke permissions, let alone allow random other apps to revoke permissions.

> Having keyboard app with permissions FINE LOCATION and internet - it is weird to allow such permissions.

Agreed. Do not install that app.

Comment: So only way is to root?

Comment: @MingChi: Avoiding installing the app would not require root.

Comment: Starting with Android M, some permissions can be managed at runtime. Location is one of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Android M preview enables you to manage some permissions (like location) at runtime: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

With a rooted device, you can disable some app permissions on older Android versions, for that you can for example use the [Xposed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053) framework.